# How to merge branch into trunk in Eclipse 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge-conflict-resolution

Trying to merge branch back into the trunk but every time I do it doesn't seem to detect any changes. Please help

Comment: It could be helpful if you shared with us details of each step you're making.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to merge, you must have checked out the *destination* in your local workspace. The concept is, you merge *from* another branch (source) *into* the current one (destination). So in your situation, make sure you have committed all your changes to the branch, then switch to trunk, then do the merge *from* branch.

Comment: What do you mean by checked out the destination? When it does recognise the changes and and I click accept it still doesn't update anything.